# Hide custom dropdown menu li once input checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I have a custom dropdown menu in pure html . i have tried everything to get it to close but nothing works. I just want it to close once something was selected / somewhere outside the menu is clicked. it appears as my custom css is preventing any simple solution.

here is the code i have for it and css and current js. i understand that this may be a frequently asked question but im still a novice at javascript and even though i feel as if i've implemented all the solutions  i could,  its possible i havent done so correctly. thank you

```js
$('#dropdown li').click(function() {
  $(".dd-button:first-child").text($(this).text());
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: -25%;
}

.dd-button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 375px;
}

.dd-button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 90%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}

.dd-button:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.dd-input {
  display: none;
}

.dd-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 375px;
}

.dd-input+.dd-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dd-input:checked+.dd-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dd-menu li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dd-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.dd-menu li a {
  display: block;
  margin: -10px -20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.dd-menu li.divider {
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="result"></div>
  <label class="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <div class="dd-button"> Selection</div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="dd-input center-block" id="test">
    <ul id = "dropdown"  class="dd-menu">
      <li>plan1 </li>
      <li>plan2 </li>
      <li>plan3 </li>
      <li>Plan4 </li>
    </ul>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Javascript.

Include `id` to you `<h1>`

```
$('#dropdown li').click(function() {
  $('#result').replaceWith('<h1 id="result">' + $(this).text() + '</h1>');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show hide popover
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {
    $(this).find("#dropdown").slideDown("fast");
  });
});

$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  var $trigger = $(".dropdown");
  if ($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length) {
    $("#dropdown").slideUp("fast");
  }
});
```

And you can even hide the `dropdown` by `$('.dropdown').hide();`

---

```js
$('#dropdown li').click(function() {
  $('#result').replaceWith('<h1 id="result">' + $(this).text() + '</h1>');
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  // Show hide popover
  $(".dropdown").click(function() {
    $(this).find("#dropdown").slideDown("fast");
  });
});

$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  var $trigger = $(".dropdown");
  if ($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length) {
    $("#dropdown").slideUp("fast");
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: -25%;
}

.dd-button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 375px;
}

.dd-button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 90%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}

.dd-button:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.dd-input {
  display: none;
}

.dd-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 375px;
}

.dd-input+.dd-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dd-input:checked+.dd-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dd-menu li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dd-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.dd-menu li a {
  display: block;
  margin: -10px -20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.dd-menu li.divider {
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="result"></div>
  <label class="dropdown" name="dropdown">
           <div class="dd-button"> Selection</div>
             <input type="checkbox" class="dd-input center-block" id="test">
                    <ul id = "dropdown"  class="dd-menu">
                         <li>plan1 </li>
                         <li>plan2 </li>
                         <li>plan3 </li>
                         <li>Plan4 </li>
                    </ul>
          </label>
</div>
```

Comment: but the dropdown still needs to be there, i just want to hide the dropdown plans upon selection of an li element , or if the user clicks outside of the dropdown.

Comment: Please explain more of what is the final requirement. You can keep the drop-down by removing the second command in JS

Comment: the final requirement is after the user selects an option, the options menu closes again. its supposed to look the same as before it was clicked. not disappear

Comment: Check the edit, it allows you to select the option again, same as before.

Comment: @DhavalJardosh you're missing the point. when you drop the list and *don't* select an item, but click away from the ddl, the list stays open. It should close.

Comment: thats good! now is there a way so that if the user opens a menu but the click outside the menu, it will close the menu? like if they click anywhere on the body of the page

Comment: Sorry about that, tons of things going around. Answer updated, thanks @wazz and jrdev for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `$(event.target).hasClass()` condition to open or hide the dropdown...

Also don't use `div` inside a `label` because

```
Element div not allowed as child of element label in this context.
```

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$('#dropdown li').click(function() {
  $(".dd-button:first-child").text($(this).text());
});
$(document).on("click", function(event) {
  if ($(event.target).hasClass("dd-button")) {
    $("#dropdown").slideDown("fast");
  } else {
    $("#dropdown").slideUp("fast");
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}

.dd-button {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px 30px 10px 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 375px;
}

.dd-button:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 90%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}

.dd-button:hover {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

.dd-input {
  display: none;
}

.dd-menu {
  position: relative;
  top: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0 0;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background-color: #ffffff;
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 375px;
}

.dd-input+.dd-menu {
  display: none;
}

.dd-input:checked+.dd-menu {
  display: block;
}

.dd-menu li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dd-menu li:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.dd-menu li a {
  display: block;
  margin: -10px -20px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

.dd-menu li.divider {
  padding: 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="result"></div>
  <div class="dropdown" name="dropdown">
    <div class="dd-button"> Selection</div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="dd-input center-block" id="test">
    <ul id="dropdown" class="dd-menu">
      <li>plan1 </li>
      <li>plan2 </li>
      <li>plan3 </li>
      <li>Plan4 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```